# Open a window in a test for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

My typical UI test in Winforms is of the form:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        if(RunManualTests)
        {
          TestForm form = new TestForm();
          SomeControl control = new SomeControl();
          form.Controls.Add(control);
          form.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

In WPF, there seems to be a requirement for App.xaml.  App.xaml has a `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` attribute.  Do I need to add this file?  If yes, how do I dynamically set the StartupUri?

In other words, how do translate my Winform test to WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no requirement on using `StartupUri`, you can just use

```
 Window w = new Window();
 w.Content = new TestControl();//replaces form.Controls.Add(...)
 w.ShowDialog();
```

in the appropriate C# code instead. However you need to care for this code to run in a dispatcher thread (that is, a foreground STA thread, which has a running `Dispatcher` -- usually the main thread of a WPF application).

You usually don't need any counterpart of `form.Controls.Add(...)`, because the controls are usually described in the XAML file. (However you can add them manually, too, if you really want to.)

Comment: MSTest projects do not include the required references for WPF to work. Add a WPF User Control to the project, this adds all missing references except System.Xaml.